# expected unqualified-id before '->' token

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

cpp. - ругается на цикл где if: expected unqualified-id before '->' token, не нравится Sprite

```
#include "sprite.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

Sprite::Sprite(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), QGraphicsItem() //, QGraphicsPixmapItem()
{
    currentFrame = 0;
    spriteImage = new QPixmap(":monkey.png");
    this->setPos(QPointF(-10, -10));
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{

}

QRectF Sprite::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(-10,-10,80,60); //область в которой лежит спрайт
}

void Sprite::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->drawPixmap(-10,-10, *spriteImage, currentFrame, 0, 80,60);
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
}

void Sprite::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_W)
       { Sprite->setPos(0,5); } else
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_S)
       { Sprite->setPos(0,-5); } else
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_A)
       { Sprite->setPos(-5,0); } else
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_D)
       { Sprite->setPos(5,0); }
}

void Sprite::slotGameTimer() 
{
        if(this->x() - 10 < -250){
            this->setX(-240);       // слева
        }
        if(this->x() + 10 > 250){
            this->setX(240);        // справа
        }

        if(this->y() - 10 < -250){
            this->setY(-240);       // сверху
        }
        if(this->y() + 10 > 250){
            this->setY(240);        // снизу
        }
     /* Проверка выхода за границы поля */
}
```

На всякий случай хедер

```
#define SPRITE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsScene> 
#include <QKeyEvent>


class Sprite : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem //, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QPointF pos READ pos WRITE setPos)

public:
    explicit Sprite(QObject *parent = 0);
    QPointF pos() const;
    void setPos(QPointF newPos);
    //sprite();
    ~Sprite(); 

signals:

public slots:
    void slotGameTimer(); 

private:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

private:
   // QTimer *timer;
    QPixmap *spriteImage;
    int currentFrame;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

};

#endif // SPRITE_H
```

Не понимаю, что не так. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

У вас `Sprite` - название класса, класс не может быть слева от оператора `->`. Если вам нужно вызвать метод текущего объекта класса, пишите:

```
this->setPos(0,5);
```

или

```
setPos(0,5);
```

---

Не заметил сразу, у вас переопределён метод `setPos`, не являющийся виртуальным. Определите, какой метод вам нужен: метод вашего класса `Sprite` или класса `QGraphicsItem`. Выберите один из следующих вариантов:

```
QGraphicsItem::setPos(0,5);
Sprite::setPos(QPointF(0,5));
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделала. Теперь выдаёт ошибку 'QGraphicsItem' is an ambiguous base of 'Sprite', в mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Всё равно та же ошибка остаётся, ambiguous base. И, кстати, если реализовывать алгоритм Switch-Case - она же. 
Через некоторое время смогу опубликовать код mainwindow, была бы очень благодарна за помощь, а то мне пока не очень понятно(

Comment: Но если коротко, то в строчке
 scene->addItem(new Sprite()); 
указывает на последнюю скобку с этой ошибкой

Comment: А, вот и получилось полный код опубликовать.

Comment: Попробуйте отнаследоваться только от QGraphicsObject (он сам отнаследован от Item и Object)

Comment: И что это у вас за #define SPRITE_H в самом верху? Напишите либо #pragma once, либо #ifndef/#define