# 'QGraphicsItem' is an ambiguous base of 'Sprite', в mainwindow.cpp

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

К предыдущему вопросу. После фикса той проблемы выдаёт ошибку 'QGraphicsItem' is an ambiguous base of 'Sprite', в mainwindow.cpp. В строчке scene->addItem(new Sprite());
Код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "sprite.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); //2
    this->resize(800,600); //2
    //this->setFixedSize(800,600); //2
    ui->graphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff); /// Отключаем скроллбар по вертикали
    ui->graphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff); /// Отключаем скроллбар по горизонтали

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(); //инициализация сцены
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene); //добавление сцены в графиксвью
    scene->addItem(new Sprite()); //добавление места под спрайт
    sprite = new Sprite(); //инициализация спрайта 2

    // дальше 2

    ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);    /// Устанавливаем сглаживание
    scene->setSceneRect(-250,-250,500,500); /// Устанавливаем область графической сцены

    //Sprite->setPos(0,0);

    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, sprite, &Sprite::slotGameTimer);
    timer->start(1000/50);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Хедер

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QList>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QShortcut> //2
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

#include "sprite.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : /*public QObject,*/ public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene; //объявляем графическую сцену
    Sprite *sprite; //2
    QTimer *timer; //2
    /*этот таймер уже не для анимации самого спрайта,
     * а для управления им с кнопок и мышки*/

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Очистка и запуск qmake не помогают.

Comment: Покажите код объявления класса `Sprite`. Вы где-то чего-то лишнего нанаследовали

Comment: @BeardedBeaver https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988817/